# Iterate through table and get last element of each object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am making a question and answer application on Rails. How do I create a page that lists all the questions and displays the last answer to that question just below it?

This is my answers controller:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @questions = Question.all
    end
end
```

Question and answer models:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Index view:

```
<% if @questions.blank? %>
    <p>No questions to display</p>
<% else %>
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
        <h2><%= question.title %></h2>
        <!-- This is where the answer should appear.
        It should be the last answer in the question. -->
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I got the title to appear but can't get the body to work.

I am sorry for the bad title but SO didn't allow me to write "question" in the title.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this-

```
<% if @questions.blank? %>
  <p>No questions to display</p>
<% else %>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <h2><%= question.title %></h2>
    <!-- This is where the answer should appear.
    It should be the last answer in the question. -->
    <%= question.answers.last %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you but it did not work.  It gives me this error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: answers.question_id: SELECT  "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = ?  ORDER BY "answers"."id" DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Do you have the `question_id` foreign key in table `answers` ?

Comment: Yes! That was the problem. I had already generated the migration without the references. Thanks a lot! Sorry for the late reply.